# developer.apple.com is not responding properly (very slow)

Tags: macos, safari, mobile-safari, iphone-developer-program

From last 2 days (from 16 Feb,15), I can not Open the [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) site properly, is there any problem in their end,
I have tried from more than 4 different high speed connection using the Mac(Yosemite version 10.10.1)'s own safari(Version 8.0.2 (10600.2.5)) browser, It is responding Very slow, even after 10 min it is showing like the below image.

Is there any regional problem of apple developer site now, because One of my clint from Russia, they are saying [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) is opening smoothly there. But [apple.com](http://apple.com) is opening easily here also.
Can any one know, why it is not opening in Kolkata, India? is there any regional problem for developer account now?

[image: Screenshot after 10min of waiting]

EDIT: I have also tried with Mozila firefox and Google chrome, same issue, responding very slow.

Comment: same here, very slow ... doesnt even load

Comment: have the same problem in germany. website is responding fast, but membercenter and resources dont even load most of the time...

Comment: Member Centre is too slow, can't bear at all, wondering why they aren't fixing it.

Comment: Even this is slow: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).